# Is there a kanji form of ああ?

Tags: kanji, demonstratives

Is there a kanji form of ああ, like there is for [斯]{こ}う, [然]{そ}う, and [如何]{どう}? I've searched online, but neither Jisho.org, Wiktionary, or Weblio list a kanji version for demonstrative ああ, like they do for [斯]{こ}う, [然]{そ}う, and [如何]{どう}.

I would assume [彼]{あ}あ, but the う/あ series of demonstratives break the [此]{こ}[其]{そ}[彼]{あ}[何]{ど} pattern and use different kanji from the rest of the demonstratives, so that's probably wrong.

I know there is [嗚呼]{ああ} and [噫]{ああ}, but those are use to describe the sound "aa" than the demonstrative.

Is there a kanji form of ああ? Or is it safe to assume that ああ has no kanji form?

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/彼#Japanese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ああ was created by **analogy** with こう and そう only in late eightteenth century (Frellesvig, *A History of the Japanese Language*, p. 389). [Were it an inherited form, it would have been あう and then おう.] Hence, it was too late to get a specific kanji correspondence.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote above the correct kanji for ああ (there is also another kanji for ああ、嗟),

but practically **you don't need to learn kanji for demonstratives.**

They are quite obsolete and very rarely used in writing.

(I've never seen them in any context, only in a dictionary)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just because I won't use it doesn't mean I'm not allowed to learn it. I only want to know the kanji demonstratives of my own interest. It's quite obvious that demonstratives rarely use kanji; if they did I probably wouldn't be asking this question. Not everything you want to study about a language is something strictly for practical usage.